# Blank page for Custom Page of AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I went quickly through setting up a custom page on AWS Cognition.

However when I go to the corresponding website:

`https://**<custom-domain>**.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/`

I get a blank page.

Answer (score 6):

found the answer at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-ux.html

> You can view the hosted UI with your customizations by constructing the following URL, with the specifics for your user pool, and typing it into a browser: 
>   `https://<your_domain>/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_app_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_callback_url>`
>   You may have to wait up to one minute to refresh your browser before changes made in the console appear.

note that `redirect_uri` need to be escaped; e.g. `/` -> `%2`

p.s. next error that you encounter might be: [invalid_request error on AWS Cognito Custom UI Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979314/invalid-request-error-on-aws-cognito-custom-ui-page/49979315)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to open the page directly from the AWS Console and stop fighting with the URL. Go to the ***App integration*** section, then scroll all the way down to ***App clients and analytics*** and click on your client. Once on your client screen, scroll down to  ***Hosted UI*** and click on ***View Hosted UI*** in the upper right corner.