# invalid_request error on AWS Cognito Custom UI Page

Tags: amazon-cognito

when going to the custom AWS Cognito UI Page:

`https://<your_domain>/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_app_client_id>`

am getting the following error:

> An error was encountered with the requested page.
>
> View error
>
> invalid_request

Answer (score 24):

O-Auth options need to be check as shown in the following picture

[image: oauth options]

from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/launch-amazon-cognito-user-pools-general-availability-app-integration-and-federation/

Answer (score 10):

You need the following in the `App client Settings` of your user pool:

- Enable `Cognito User Pool` as "Identity Provider".
- Allowed "OAuth Scopes" should have `openid` enabled.

[image: App client settings]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it appears there was some issue with verifying the phone number. So switched back to email.

[image]

This document is good for checking everything.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/launch-amazon-cognito-user-pools-general-availability-app-integration-and-federation/

Unless the SMS Sending setup is not complete, do not choose the Email or Phone option. Email or phone actually falls back to phone number only. Read the warning messages.

[image]

Comment: You're my hero!!!

Comment: Just shared my experiance.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: If you use an AWS User Pool with Cognito App Client and have an Application Load Balancer that is exposed via a custom DNS entry (e.g. `custom-domain.com`, which has to be secured via SSL), use this custom domain for the Cognito App Client's callback URL (i.e. `https://custom-domain.com/oauth2/idpresponse`) instead if the random DNS name created by AWS.

I had the same error and [this issue](https://github.com/awslabs/sagemaker-dashboards-for-ml/issues/4) solved it for me. I used a User Pool with a Cognito App Client and as callback URL I first used the DNS name that AWS created for it (`<load balancer name>-<random number>.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com`, i.e. `"callbackUrl": "https://<load balancer name>-<random number>.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com/oauth2/idpresponse`). I also created a DNS record for a custom domain to expose the load balancer to the internet and secured it via SSL. As a result, the certificate was not valid for the URL created by AWS, but only my custom domain. The Cognito App Client was thus trying to access the URL with the invalid SSL certificate and returned the error.

Answer (score 0):

for expo users, in my case, sign in whitelist wasn't correct, so I had to update it to match my expo app:

so if you're using expo, just check on which port metro is listening (see your console):

```
› Choose an app to open your project at http://192.168.1.2:8081/_expo/loading
› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.2:8081
```

then just navigate here and update by clicking on `Edit` btn of the `Hosted UI` section:
`Amazon Cognito -> User pools -> your-user-pool -> App client: your_app_client`

[image: aws config of federated sign in]