# Link/connect Google oidc external provider with aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

Recently I faced a new requirement to link or connect Google oidc external provider with aws cognito.

Background: my frontend application is running in aws and integrated with cognito for users and groups. Due to new requirements I have to connect client web application (jupyterhub) which is running on GCP vm instances.

My question is here : is this compatible or possible to use Google IAP with external oidc provider which could link to aws cognito app client and provide cognito UI to login?

Has someone faced such situation?
I would appreciate any comments or thought on this scanerio.

Many thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enable-external-identities) can authenticate users with a wide range of identity providers such as OIDC and more by combining IAP and Identity Platform.

Identity Platform can be used to sign in users with an [OpenID Connect](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc) (OIDC) provider.

Comment: I did try in this way, but didn't work and I'm not able to reach cognito UI

Comment: What error you are getting while trying to reach cognito UI?

Please remove any sensitive information while posting. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with existing hosted sign in page in IAP. When I tried to access https url. After some processing it shows an error like "An error was encountered with requested page" with cognito custom Logo.

Comment: Please follow these threads [1] [2] [3] with the similar error message you are getting. This might be helpful.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979314/invalid-request-error-on-aws-cognito-custom-ui-page

[2] https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/755

[3] https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259044